# SupportMapFragment not working , gives error

Tags: android, google-maps

when i open application first time , it shows map correctly . But when second time i open application it crash always .

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.doctordetail_map);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code , i also face this problem , this will helps you.

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.doctordetail_map);
    if (supportMapFragment == null) {
        supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.doctordetail_map, supportMapFragment).commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is due to duplicate id

destroy the map in ondestory